# Поиск всех решений тригонометрического уравнения на sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Необходимо найти все решения тригонометрического уравнения на python, используя sympy. Пробовал решить его так:

```
>>> a = simplify('sin(x)+cos(x)')
>>> a
sin(x) + cos(x)
>>> solve(a)
[-pi/4, 3*pi/4]
```

Но ответ должен получиться таким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В одной из предыдущих тем сказали, что поиск корней идёт только на определённом интервале. Как мне найти все корни данного уравнения?

Answer (score 2):

Найти все решения тригонометрического уравнения с помощью модуля `sympy` можно методом [solveset](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#module-sympy.solvers.solveset):

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
pprint(solveset(sin(x) + cos(x), x, domain=S.Reals))
```

Вывод:

```
          3*pi                                pi                   
{2*n*pi + ---- | n in Integers()} U {2*n*pi - -- | n in Integers()}
           4                                  4
```

Результат, правда, указывается с периодами 2*pi. Т.е. в ответ уходит объединение корней.

Подробнее в [документации](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/solvers.html).

Comment: Не стоит использовать `from ... import *`

Comment: Я знаю. Но во-первых, в документации все примеры так представлены. А во-вторых, сам автор вопроса так сделал. Я лишь хотел сделать код красивее.

Comment: Как вопрос так и документация подразумевают интерактивную работу в REPL, где `from module import *` допустимо. В обычном коде эту форму следует избегать (кроме специальных случаев вроде `asyncio/__init__.py`)